# ORA-00904 invalid identifier. Where is the error?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing the following query as a source in my ADF. I am getting the following error:

> ERROR [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver][Oracle]ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Need to figure out where the error is?

```sql
SELECT
    SYSDATE AS "date_stamp",
    rep.*
  FROM
    (
    SELECT
        s.subdivision,
        s.activity_grp
    FROM
        ORC.z1subdiv  s
        LEFT JOIN ORC.z1tmu t 
                   ON t.tmu = s.tmu
    WHERE       
        s.activity_grp LIKE 'Z%' AND
        t.tmu_group IN ('ABC','PQR')
    ) sub
    JOIN TABLE
    (
                  lawson_crystal.xREPORTwrapper.main
                     ( 
                        p_company_gl      => 'ALL',
                        p_activity_group =>  sub.activity_grp,
                        p_tmu        => 'ALL',
                        p_division   => 'ALL',
                        p_subdivision => sub.subdivision, 
                        p_project    => 'ALL',
                        p_exclude_statuses => 'N/A'
                       )
    ) rep ON 1 = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

This error message usually means that you are referencing a table column that doesn't exist. I would check that the column names you are using all exist in the underlying tables.